# When I change to PHP 8 my WordPress site displays errors

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a WordPress website that uses PHP 7.4. However, when I change the PHP version to 8 it gives me this error:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Undefined constant “‘WP_TEMP_DIR’” in /home/soundtri/shoppingpal.biz/wp-config.php:22 
Stack trace: 
 #0 /home/soundtri/shoppingpal.biz/wp-load.php(50): require_once() 
 #1 /home/soundtri/shoppingpal.biz/wp-blog-header.php(13): require_once(‘/home/soundtri/…’) 
 #2 /home/soundtri/shoppingpal.biz/index.php(17): require(‘/home/soundtri/…’) 
 #3 {main} thrown in /home/soundtri/shoppingpal.biz/wp-config.php on line 2
```

Comment: When you used an undefined constant before PHP 8, you only got a warning (and PHP continued by using the constant name as a string). From PHP 8, it's considered a fatal and throws an error. If it's not certain that a constant is defined, you need to check before trying to use it: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.defined

Comment: M. Eriksson I took an introductory course to PHP about 4 years ago and I never used it, that's why I use WordPress, I don't code PHP. I am not sure what to do.